# How to read information off of website using selenium, python, and MS edge

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to learn how to use selenium.  To do this I am trying to search the toronto stock exchange and get the dividend yield.  I need to know how to use MS Edge to do it, other browsers won't work.  I am able to get to the website and search for and successfully navigate to the XIC webpage.  However, when I try to get the dividend, it doesn't work.  I am using:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time

driver=webdriver.Edge() 
driver.get('https://tsx.com/')

time.sleep(3)
search=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("//*[@id='searchinputtext']"))  
search.send_keys("XIC")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) 
time.sleep(10)   
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'KeyDataContent__Value-sc-ngzvx0-4 giVypD'))
```

On the website I inspect the dividend, and it gives me:

```
<div data-testid="exDividendDate-value" class="KeyDataContent__Value-sc-ngzvx0-4 giVypD">2023-06-26</div>
```

It gives the error (I replaced some numbers and letters with X):

```
[XXXXX/XXXXX.XXXXX:ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(162)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.
[XXXXX/XXXXX:ERROR:assistance_home_client.cc(32)] File path C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dirXXXXX\Default

DevTools listening on ws://XXXXX/devtools/browser/XXXXX
[XXXXX/XXXXX.XXX:ERROR:secondary_tile_client.cc(171)] OnSecondaryTileManagerDisconnected. Sending error response to callbacks
[XXXXX/XXXXX.XXX:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/XXXXX.
[XXXXX:XXXXX:XXXXX/XXXXX.XXX:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/XXXXX.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\XXXXX\selenium\sel_try_tsx.py", line 126, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'KeyDataContent__Value-sc-ngzvx0-4 giVypD')) 
  File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 86, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I've been looking for how to do it, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Does anyone know?

Comment: "I need to know how to use MS Edge to do it, other browsers won't work" <- can you explain this

Comment: The browser I am using is MS Edge.  I read something about Selenium 4 not working on it, but I think that was outdated information.  There's a database I access through a program which only runs through MS Edge.

Comment: Please provide your code as a [mre]. Otherwise, the only thing we could say is that you are invoking/calling a non-callable `list` object.